# How to enable USB access blocked using group policy

Tags: group-policy, usb

My USB Access is blocked using Group Policy.
How can I enable it? I am using Windows XP professional 2002

Comment: Its probably been blocked for a reason!!

Answer (score 2):

You will need to ask your systems administrator or helpdesk team as they will have locked down the access you have :-)